# ISteamRemoteStorage access without paying submission fee?

Tags: c++, steam, steamworks-api

I was wondering if without paying the submission fee on Steamworks, I could still access to Steam Remote Storage's functions?

Because when I try to call the FileWrite method, it returns me 'false' (file was not written...). I'm well connected to the Steam API, I can get my username, my friends and so on. I can also see that when I launch my game, it launches on Steam the placeholder app 'Spacewar' - so I was wondering if writing to the Steam Cloud would work with this placeholder app (for testing purposes) or if I need to pay the fee, create my own app and then can access to the Steam Cloud functions?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Steam Support rather than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

According to [PCGamingWiki](https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Spacewar) Spacewar has very limited Steam Cloud storage capability -- 39 chars per file limited to letters, numbers, and spaces, and a max of 10 files. So, you may be able to use that for some **extremely simple** Cloud save testing.

Based on the [SteamWorks documentation](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/cloud) for the Steam Cloud and how it works though, yes, you'll need to pay the fee (bold for emphasis):

> ... NOTE: Don't forget to click Save at the bottom of the page, and Publish your updated settings. Once published the cloud icon will be visible in the Steam client for anyone that **owns your game**.